# Jira Service desk, create request from an email without creating accounts

Tags: jira

We have a support email box like "support@xyz.com". If some one sends an email to that, our help desk currently responds to that email.

We are trying to implement JIRA Service Desk, where in if someone sends an email to that box, we want to create a corresponding support ticket in JIRA. What we are facing now is, if some random person sends an email to that box, JIRA does create the ticket, but also sends an Jira Customer Sign up email to the person who send that request. We dont want to them to sign up or view our JIRA portal. We are using JIRA cloud.

Does anyone have ideas on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create a request via email without creating a new account or using existing one. Also, there is no way to disable an invitation email when JIRA creates a customer automatically. There is a similar request in Atlassian: [JSDCLOUD-1827](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSDCLOUD-1827).

The only way that comes up to my mind is to replace "From" email with your existing internal account's email with the help of [JEMHC add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.javahollic.jira.jemh-ui/cloud/overview). There is an [example](https://thepluginpeople.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JEMHC/Forward+an+email+to+JIRA+as+the+sender) in the documentation related to editing the "From" field in incoming emails.